# PHP Function to Delphi Function

Tags: php, delphi, encryption

I am trying to create a PHP script, and a Delphi program to "talk" with it. In order to keep it secure, I want to encrypt the outgoing text from both sides, so it makes to use the same encryption function on both ends.

This is the function I found for PHP:

```
function convert($str,$ky=''){
  if($ky=='')return $str;
  $ky=str_replace(chr(32),'',$ky);
  if(strlen($ky)<8)exit('key error');
  $kl=strlen($ky)<32?strlen($ky):32;
  $k=array();
  for($i=0;$i<$kl;$i++){
    $k[$i]=ord($ky{$i})&0x1F;
  }
  $j=0;
  for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++){
    $e=ord($str{$i});
    $str{$i}=$e&0xE0?chr($e^$k[$j]):chr($e);
    $j++;
    $j=$j==$kl?0:$j;
  }
  return $str;
}
```

I cant seem to be able to convert it to Delphi. Help is greatly apreciated!
Thanks, Jeff

Comment: What have you got so far? Which lines specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: That looks pretty darn *secure* to me

Comment: First step: Format the code so it's readable. Line break after each semicolon, indentations inside "if" and "for" blocks, spaces around binary operators.

Comment: @Rob, I did the code formatting before reading your comment.

Comment: @Rob , thats the code I found. @David , sarcasm? :P @webbiedave , the Array part.

Comment: @Jeff Since this isn't at all secure, why not choose something simpler that conceals your data, for example some `xor` operations, possibly with some shuffling if you want to get fancy.

Comment: @Jeff Also, the correct spelling is *Whizz* rather than *Wiz*, a *Wiz* is something entirely different, it's what you emit when you micturate

Comment: @David, I am not keen on the XOR, SHR, SHL stuff.. As I said, the PHP code above I found on a forum. If you could provide an example, that would be awesome!

Comment: @Jeff OK, if you don't like xor then do it your own way

Comment: @David, Aah, thanks :P Gotta remake the graphic then, dont think I saved the project file :P

Comment: @David, its not that I dont like it, I said I am not keen with it, meaning I dont really know how to do it :P So I was asking for an example :)

Comment: @Jeff You threw away the project for your graphic? Your graphic is also not 17th birthday compliant!

Comment: @Jeff show us your Delphi code and then we'll be able to help. If you haven't got any try, and then post when you are totally stuck.

Comment: author attribution has been conveniently lost in space, http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showpost.php?p=10742132&postcount=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a function that receives two strings and returns another string. I'll include variable declarations in comments as they're introduced in the code; put them at the top of the function.

```
function convert(str: AnsiString; const key: AnsiString = ''): AnsiString;
```

If the key is empty, then the result is simply `str`:

```
begin
  if key = '' then
    Exit(str);
```

The first parameter is the value to be "encrypted," and the second is the key to use for that encryption. The key needs to be at least eight non-space characters long; anything beyond 32 is ignored. If the key is too short, the PHP script would terminate; we'll use Delphi's `Assert` statement instead since it's clear that the code should never even have executed if the key is wrong. (Script-termination is not a recoverable error that the user would be expected to fix.) The PHP code uses the `?:` operator to select the desired value for the length, but Delphi's `Min` function (from the *Math* unit) expresses the desire more clearly.

```
  // var ky: AnsiString;
  ky := StringReplace(key, ' ', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Assert(Length(ky) >= 8, 'key error');
  // var kl: Integer;
  kl := Min(Length(ky), 32);
```

The array `k` is used to hold numbers representing the lower five bits of each character in the key. In PHP, an array will automatically grow to whatever size it needs based on the index used. In Delphi, we need to allocate the space in advance. Since it's set in a loop that goes over each character of the key, we know the array will be the same length.

```
  // var k: array of Byte;
  SetLength(k, kl);
  // var i: Integer;
  for i := 0 to Pred(kl) do
    k[i] := Ord(ky[i+1]) and $1f;
```

Next, each character in the string that has its seventh bit set gets modified according to each successive byte in the `k` array. The `j` variable keeps track of which key byte we'll use next.

```
  // var j: Integer;
  j := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(str) do begin
    // var e: Byte;
    e := Ord(str[i]);
    if (e and $e0) <> 0 then
      str[i] := AnsiChar(e xor k[j]);
    Inc(j);
    if j = kl then
      j := 0;
    // The previous three lines can also be written j := (j + 1) mod kl
  end;
```

Finally, we return the new value of `str`:

```
  Result := str;
end;
```

Comment: +1 You earned some rep there. You still should have let Jeff try himself first though since that would have helped his learning.

Comment: @Rob Thanks! It wont compile though, I run D2010. Maybe I should have said that earlier huh?

Comment: @Jeff Are you really asking Rob to fix a couple of minor compilation problems? Surely you can do that?

Comment: Lol, AVG now picks it up as a virus.. :P

Comment: @Jeff I cannot believe that you have not up-voted this answer. To me that would appear rude and ungrateful so I can only assume it is a simple, honest omission.

Comment: @David I have not accepted it yet, as I have not gotten it to work yet.

Comment: @Jeff Not accept, up-vote! Be generous, Rob spent quite some time on that, and explained what he was doing. First of all you complained that it didn't compile. Then you made some joke about a virus. Really, if you show a bit of gratitude then it will encourage people to help you. I'm only trying to be constructively helpful myself, because I know that you are still young and impressionable.

Comment: @David, I really apreciate that, and I did up vote it. Just had to test it first. I got it working now, it reported it as a virus cause I did not call the func yet. Also, this function does sadly not return the same as the PHP function?

Comment: @Jeff It's Rob you mean to thank I think! Anyway, I think I corrected a couple of the minor errors in Rob's original. I'm sure he wrote it without a compiler at hand. Very good work!

Comment: @David I did thank him. :) Will test the edited code now, to see if it returns the same as the PHP script. EDIT: Nope. Hmm..

Comment: @Jeff Out of interest, presumably you have to write a decoder as well an encoder?

Comment: @David - the function does both, thats the beauty of it ;) The thing is though, the Delphi code does not return the same encrypted text as the PHP script does. :)

Comment: @Jeff So it's like an obfuscated rot13!

Comment: @David - as long as I can use IdHTTP.Post without anyone being able to read the text being sent and received, I am happy. Thats why I need encryption, so they can read as much as they want, but unless they know the function and secret key, they cant read it. That is also why I need the PHP func and the Delphi func, to use the same encryption. My program will encrypt some text, use POST to send it to the PHP script, the PHP script will then decrypt it, do its business, encrypt the result, send it back, and my app will Decrypt it again.

Comment: @Jeff I think I can see what's missing. Just wait a minute and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Jeff no, I retract that, Rob's code looks identical to the PHP

Comment: @David, I just tested it. My key is "mysecretkey", and my original text is "test", this is what the PHP script returns: "y|`q". This is what Delphi returns: "thjg"

Comment: @Jeff and @David, it seems like a good bench test would be simply delphi to delphi. i.e. take PHP out of the equation until you can get the same string back when calling it from another Delphi function.

Comment: @Chris, if you mean decrypting the text again, that works fine. :)

Comment: @Chris @Jeff the Delphi code is reversible, I think Jeff's PHP code is wrong!!

Comment: @David - as I said, the PHP code was from a forum post, I did not make it myself. Also, the PHP code is reversable aswell.

Comment: @Jeff @Chris @Rob No I've got it, I'll edit the correct in just one second, it's to the line where k[i] is assigned. A classic case of 0-based arrays and 1-based strings, one Delphi design decision that I'm sure everyone at Embarcadero wish they could reverse with the aid of a time machine!

Comment: @David S.O should let me vote up more than once, cause you just fixed it! Thanks alot, and thanks alot Rob! How did you know where it was failing? Thats amazing dude!

Comment: @Jeff I did what you could have done! I added to the PHP an `echo $k[$i];` in the loop and looked at what the $k buffer contained. I did the same in Delphi and they differed. I looked harder at the code and out popped the bug. Back when I was a 16 year old computer W(h)iz(z) we didn't have the internet and we had to solve all our problems ourselves. I'm not saying things were better in those distant days, but it's a good discipline for you to learn how to debug issues like this.

Comment: @David I am not familiar with all the fancy byte stuff - Win API rocks! Haha, I have to learn it for sure. But thanks again!

Comment: @Jeff It's not hard. You need to learn about bitwise operators, and, or, not, xor. Use Wikipedia, for example.

Comment: @David, thanks for finding and fixing the problem. You're right that I didn't have a compiler when I wrote this; it's been over three years since I've compiled Delphi code. What's funny is that you don't really need to know what the bitwise operators are doing to do this translation. All you need to know is that `^` means `xor` and `&` means `and`.

Comment: @rob so is your delphi stack overflow activity a hark back to the good old days?!

Answer (score 1):

Have at the [Delphi Cryptography Package](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/cryptography.html) by David Barton.  There is an small example which shows how to get PHP and Delphi encryption working together.

Answer (score -3):

I think you really need to bridge your app, then take a look at this, 'cause it is a litte bit complex to try explain here. Actually it is usefull to integrate app PHP/Java via bridge, but I think exists something on that way to integrate PHP/Delphi also via bridge.

[ZEND Server](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/)

Comment: -1. I cannot see how this is a helpful answer at all. If you really  think it answers the question, then please edit your answer to make it more clear what "bridging" an application means and why Zend Server would allow Jeff to do that. Also explain how he would use that in his Delphi program.

Comment: You've basically told him to "bridge the app", when he's basically already asking how to do that. "how do I tie my shoe?" "by tieing it"

Comment: All I want is to get that function converted to Delphi.

Comment: If I could vote you down again for that "figure it out" remark, I'd do it. The point of answering questions on Stack Overflow is to help others figure things out. If you can't be bothered with that, then I suggest you find something else to do.

Comment: @Rob I was able to do it for you!! But Jeff provoked that reaction with his clumsy "I want".

Comment: @David, I think you misunderstood that, what I meant is, what I am looking for, is a translation of the code, not a whole application. You tend to misunderstand me a lot mate :p

Comment: @Jeff It's easy to misunderstand when communication is in this written stilted form. It's always worth trying to state things softly if you are asking other people for help. "All I want" sounds impatient and demanding. You could have written "I'm not sure I need anything this complex, I'm really just looking for a translation of this code into Delphi". Same message, but less chance of anyone reacting badly.

Comment: @jeff is was a nice try to help, if you got "minded injured", no problem just do not answer and try to find a solution for your problems, it looks like someone wanna fight.. ahahahha do not need to cry out, just ignore the post. I really holp you solve your problem man.

Comment: @Fernando, was not injured in anyway, this is the Internet :P Thanks mate :)

Comment: I dont get why so many people down-repped this answer. He was just trying to help out..

Comment: thats how stack overflow works.  Although he tried to help, he didn't really help at all.  So the answer is down-voted.  Its not personal, its how the good answers make it to the top.

Comment: And he can earn a cool badge for deleting a downvoted answer (peer pressure badge). I've got one!!

Comment: @Jeff You are right is just the internet, but I sure you, a lot of people here is earning money ad work under the internet, is just internet and real make money life. I think you are here try to find a solution for someone else that is paying money for you, or you are just a kid playing around without a real purpose to do what you are trying to do, or better trying to find a solution. In no way it is personal, all right man? then to me the discussion is over. One more time good luck for you.